# scipy.optimize.minimize function with L-BFGS-B method maxiter attribute not working

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a simple cost function, which I want to optimize using scipy.optimize.minimize  function.

```
opt_solution  = scipy.optimize.minimize(costFunction, theta, args = (training_data,), method = 'L-BFGS-B', jac = True, options = {'maxiter': 100)
```

where `costFunction` is the function to be optimized, `theta` are the parameters to be optimized. Inside `costFunction`, I printed the value of cost function. But the parameter `maxiter` seems to have no effect whether I increase value from 10 to 100000. The time it is taking is same. Also, I was expecting the printed value of cost function should be equal to the values of `maxiter`. So I am feeling `maxiter` has no effect. What might be the problem  ?
Cost function is

```
def costFunction(self, theta, input):

    """ Extract weights and biases from 'theta' input """

    W1 = theta[self.limit0 : self.limit1].reshape(self.hidden_size, self.visible_size)
    W2 = theta[self.limit1 : self.limit2].reshape(self.visible_size, self.hidden_size)
    b1 = theta[self.limit2 : self.limit3].reshape(self.hidden_size, 1)
    b2 = theta[self.limit3 : self.limit4].reshape(self.visible_size, 1)

    """ Compute output layers by performing a feedforward pass
        Computation is done for all the training inputs simultaneously """

    hidden_layer = self.sigmoid(numpy.dot(W1, input) + b1)
    output_layer = self.sigmoid(numpy.dot(W2, hidden_layer) + b2)

    """ Compute intermediate difference values using Backpropagation algorithm """

    diff = output_layer - input
    sum_of_squares_error = 0.5 * numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(diff, diff)) / input.shape[1]
    weight_decay         = 0.5 * self.lamda * (numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(W1, W1)) + numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(W2, W2)))
    cost                 = sum_of_squares_error + weight_decay 

    """ Compute the gradient values by averaging partial derivatives
        Partial derivatives are averaged over all training examples """

    W1_grad = numpy.dot(del_hid, numpy.transpose(input))
    W2_grad = numpy.dot(del_out, numpy.transpose(hidden_layer))
    b1_grad = numpy.sum(del_hid, axis = 1)
    b2_grad = numpy.sum(del_out, axis = 1)

    W1_grad = W1_grad / input.shape[1] + self.lamda * W1
    W2_grad = W2_grad / input.shape[1] + self.lamda * W2
    b1_grad = b1_grad / input.shape[1]
    b2_grad = b2_grad / input.shape[1]

    """ Transform numpy matrices into arrays """

    W1_grad = numpy.array(W1_grad)
    W2_grad = numpy.array(W2_grad)
    b1_grad = numpy.array(b1_grad)
    b2_grad = numpy.array(b2_grad)

    """ Unroll the gradient values and return as 'theta' gradient """

    theta_grad = numpy.concatenate((W1_grad.flatten(), W2_grad.flatten(),
                                    b1_grad.flatten(), b2_grad.flatten()))
    # Update counter value
    self.counter += 1                                
    print "Index ", self.counter, "cost ", cost
    return [cost, theta_grad]
```

Comment: What's your cost function?

Comment: cost function is  simple mean square error like `(x-x')^2`.

Answer (score 2):

`maxiter` gives the maximum  number of iterations that scipy will try before giving up on improving the solution. But it may very well be satisfied with a solution and stop earlier.

If you look at [the docs for `minimize` when using the `'l-bfgs-b'` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html), notice there are three parameters you can pass as options (`factr`, `ftol` and `gtol`) that can also cause the iteration to stop.

In simple cases like yours, especially if your cost function also provides the gradient (as indicated by `jac=True` in your call), convergence typically happens in the first few iterations, hence way before the `maxiter` limit is reached.

Comment: ok. I understood. It may be the case. Also one weird thing is : the number of times the cost function is called shouldn't be equal to `maxiter` value ? In my case, it is different values. I was printing this value for verification.

Comment: If you are giving it the gradient they should be pretty close, I think, although there may be some extra calls during setup, hard to tell without looking at the actual source code.

Comment: I edited my code with cost function now. The function is long. But I hope it will be easier for understanding.